# convert to datetime and format date in pandas in a single oneliner

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, format

I have a dataframe with two columns containing dates non formated.

the data in such columns is as follows:
2011-06-10T00:00:00.000+02:00

I would like to get just the date and format it.

In a Jupyter notebook I do the followings:

```
sections['produced'] = pd.to_datetime(sections['produced'])
sections['produced'] = [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if not pd.isnull(d) else '' for d in sections['produced']]

sections['updated'] = pd.to_datetime(sections['updated'])
sections['updated'] = [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if not pd.isnull(d) else '' for d in sections['updated']]

sections.info()
```

Then I print out the sections dataframe and indeed the dates are printed correctly.

BUT:

```
sections.info()
```

still tells me that those columns are non-null objects and not datetime.
Why?

secondly, my approach does not seem to work under the hood, i.e. the date types are not actually dates.
What should I do?
And last, the code is super verbose for something that should be one liner, or not? (i.e. pandas is powerful but has his limits)

EDIT 1: Answering some of the contributors. I expect datetime. just 2008-02-02 just the day.
So when doing:

```
sections['updated'] = pd.to_datetime(sections['updated'])
```

the date type is converted.
but when doing next:

```
sections['produced'] = [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if not pd.isnull(d) else '' for d in sections['produced']]
```

So the aim here is to a) covert to datetime format b) get the date format 2008-01-02, I dont care about seconds c) it has to be printed out in jupyter notebook as such, i.e. as date

Comment: What dtypes do you expect? What *does* `sections.info()` print? What do you mean by "non formated"? `2011-06-10T00:00:00.000+02:00` is pretty standard ISO 8601...

Comment: Once you got `''` mixed with other data types in the column, the dtype is always object.

Comment: @QuangHoang looks like the OP wants to format to string, so it is object anyway

Comment: @MrFuppes *still tells me that those columns are non-null objects and not datetime* near the end seems to look for datetime type.

Comment: @QuangHoang yup, but `strftime` doesn't return that ;-) OP should clarify.

Comment: I hope I clarify now

Comment: Ok so if you want datetime dtype, just use `pd.to_datetime(column_name)`. If you want string formatted as yyyy-mm-dd, use `pd.to_datetime(column_name).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`. Note that you cannot change how pandas *displays* the datetime values, but that shouldn't worry you as long as your *working* with the data. To get a "human-readable" output, format to string as described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just pass `errors` parameter in `to_datetime()` method and set that equal to **'coerce'**:-

```
sections['produced'] = pd.to_datetime(sections['produced'],errors='coerce')
sections['updated'] = pd.to_datetime(sections['updated'],errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work as a one liner:

```
df[['produced','updated']] = df[['produced','updated']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x,errors='coerce'))
```

Comment: This works in terms of data type, now ['produced','updated'] are datetype, but when printing in jupyter notebook I still see: 2011-04-18 00:00:00+02:00 under both columns. passing format='%Y-%m-%d' does not seem to work.